# Сообщающиеся сосуды Python

Tags: python, олимпиада

Два дня не могу решить задачу:

> Сегодня на уроке физики рассказывали удивительные вещи. Придя домой,
> Витя решил проверить слова учителя о том, что если взять два
> одинаковых сосуда, соединённых тонкой трубкой на уровне основания, то
> уровень жидкости при любом её количестве также будет одинаковым для
> обоих сосудов.
>
> Способ убедиться в правильности утверждения Витя избрал довольно
> оригинальный. Он взял аквариум с основанием длиной N и шириной 1,
> очень высокими стенками и поставил N–1 перегородок параллельно узкой
> боковой стенке аквариума, тем самым разделив аквариум на N одинаковых
> отсеков. Каждая перегородка имеет ширину 1 и очень большую высоту.
> Толщиной перегородки можно пренебречь. В каждой из перегородок есть
> точечное отверстие на высоте Hi, диаметром которого также можно
> пренебречь. После всех этих приготовлений Витя медленно наливает в
> первый отсек (между стенкой и первой перегородкой) C литров воды. В
> часть аквариума размером 1×1×1 вмещается ровно один литр воды. Так как
> стенки и перегородки в аквариуме были очень высокими, то через край
> вода не переливалась. После установления стационарного состояния он
> замерил уровень жидкости в каждом из N сосудов.
>
> Теперь он хочет убедиться, что его экспериментальные данные не
> опровергают законы, рассказанные на уроке. Он обратился к вам с
> просьбой выяснить, какой должна быть высота жидкости в каждом из
> сосудов с теоретической точки зрения.
>
> Рассмотрим подробно случай N=3. Пусть сначала H1<H2. Как только
> жидкость в первом отсеке достигнет уровня первого отверстия, вода
> станет поступать во второй отсек до тех пор, пока уровни в обоих
> отсеках не сравняются (или уровень воды в первом отсеке окажется
> равным H1, тогда во втором отсеке он будет на уровне C–H1). Далее
> уровень жидкости в первых двух частях будет увеличиваться равномерно
> (или не будет меняться). Как только вода достигнет второго отверстия,
> вся она будет поступать в третий отсек, опять же до тех пор, пока
> уровни жидкости во всех трёх частях не сравняются или вода в первых
> двух отсеках достигнет уровня H2. После этого, если воды оказалось
> достаточно, весь аквариум будет заполняться равномерно.
>
> Пусть теперь H1>H2. Как только жидкость в первом отсеке достигнет
> уровня первого отверстия, вся вода станет поступать во второй отсек.
> Если после этого уровень во втором отсеке сравняется с уровнем второго
> отверстия, то вода станет выливаться в третий до тех пор, пока высоты
> жидкостей во втором и третьем отсеках не станут равными. Далее уровень
> воды в них будет равномерно увеличиваться, пока не достигнет первого
> отверстия. После этого весь аквариум будет заполняться равномерно.

**Входные данные**

В первой строке записаны целые `N` и `C` `( 1 ≤ N ≤ 100000, 0 ≤ C ≤ 2 ⋅ 109)`. В следующих `N–1` строках содержится по одному целому числу `Hi (0 ≤ Hi ≤ 2 ⋅ 109)`, обозначающему высоту отверстия в i-й перегородке.

**Выходные данные**

Выведите N чисел, каждое на новой строке — уровень жидкости в `1,2,...,N` отсеке соответственно.

**Примеры**

```
Ввод:
4 4
3
2
1
Вывод:
3.00000000000000000000
1.00000000000000000000
0.00000000000000000000
0.00000000000000000000
```

```
Ввод:
4 10
1
2
3
Вывод:
3.00000000000000000000
3.00000000000000000000
3.00000000000000000000
0.99999999999999911000
```

Вот такое решение не проходит по времени:

```py
from math import fabs
 
NN = 1000000
eps = 1e-7
h = [0 for _ in range(NN)]
 
def get_h():
    global a, h, s
    assert (s < t)
    return a[h[s]]
 
 
def pop_h():
    global s, h
    assert (s < t)
    s += 1
    return h[s - 1]
 
 
def push_h(x):
    global t, h, s, a
    while s < t and a[h[t - 1]] < a[x]:
        t -= 1
    h[t] = x
    t += 1
 
 
n, C = str(input()).split()
n = int(n)
C = float(C)
a = [0 for _ in range(NN)]
for i in range(n - 1):
    a[i] = int(input())
p = [0 for i in range(n)]
s = 0
t = 0
i = 0
j = 1
l = C
r = 0
push_h(0)
while j < n and i < j  and l > (a[j - 1] + eps):
    ev1 = (l - r) * (j - i) / (j - i + 1)
    if s < t:
        ev2 = (l - get_h()) * (j - i)
        ev = min(ev2, ev1)
    else:
        ev = ev1
    l -= (ev / (j - i))
    r += ev
    if fabs(l - r) < eps:
        push_h(j)
        j += 1
        r = 0
    if fabs(l - get_h()) < eps:
        x = pop_h()
        while i <= x:
            p[i] = l
            i += 1
        i = x + 1
    if (i == j) or (l < a[j - 1] + eps):
        while i < j:
            p[i] = l
            i += 1
        l = r
        r = 0
        i = j
        push_h(j)
        j += 1
while i < j:
    p[i] = l
    i += 1
for i in range(n):
    print(p[i])
```

Comment: ну тут должно быть решение за O(n), так как иначе по времени не пройдет ,проще всего смоделировать ситуацию. Мы пройдемся по всем значением 1 раз. на каждой итерации мы можем узнать сколько останется а сколько перельется